# .Net Core connect to a Windows Printer

Tags: .net, f#

NET 6 and F#. Hardware interaction is a new field!

I’m trying to connect to a printer that is installed on Windows and has a name “PRINTERNAME”. I was previously using a PHP library that could connect with that name, but the .NET library I was using cannot. So going to attempt it myself.

The printer is connected via USB.

What is the best way to connect and simply verify that that printer exists on the local machine?

I’m using F#, but it’s more of a framework question as I have no idea what type of interfaces or libraries to use.

Comment: I've never done this myself, but maybe System.Drawing.Printing from the platform compat pack has something? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with this, but I don't think there's any way to "connect" to a printer in .NET without actually printing something.

One thing you can do instead is enumerate the printers installed on your system:

```ml
open System.Drawing.Printing   // Nuget package: System.Drawing.Common

for printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters do
    printfn "%s" printer
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) for the `PrinterSettings` class might have more useful information for you.

Comment: This definitely works. Any tutorials for printing that you're aware of? The ESCPOS libraries I'm looking at don't map as cleanly to F# as I'd like.

Comment: I think your best bet is to follow a C# printing tutorial and translate it to F#. The translation should be pretty straightforward. [Here's one](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44330-printing-in-c%23/) that look promising.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This is Windows only.

I see that other answers help you *enumerate* existing printers - but they don't help you *add new printers*.

Unfortunately, I don't have an F# answer for you.  But, I have a C# answer that you may be able to convert to F#.  (Sorry, my F# knowledge isn't good enough to know what to do here!)

---

The normal ["Add Printer" dialog (image)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/storage/attachments/43518-image.png) is handled by the DLL `printui.dll`, in the function `PrintUIEntry`.  You can run this function manually, by executing `rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /il` at a command prompt.  (Run the command `rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry` to see a help dialog)

---

Now - how do you do this from *code*?  While you could certainly call `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`, calling `rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry` with the appropriate arguments, you could also use P/Invoke interop.

... Unfortunately, it seems that, at least according to [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=printui&namespace=%5BAll%5D), that the P/Invoke interop call is really nothing more than a different way of doing the same thing.

---

Example code (again, sorry, C#)

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("printui.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void PrintUIEntryW(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hinst, string lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);

public static void ConnectToSharedPrinter(
    string uncPath,
    string? driverFile,
    bool setAsDefault
)
{
    uncPath = uncPath ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uncPath));

    var command = $"/n {uncPath}";
    if(setAsDefault)
        command = command + " /y";
    command = driverFile is null
        ? command + " /id"
        : command + $" /if /f ""{driverFile}""";
    PrintUIEntryW(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, ", command, 0);
}
```